# Unit Test for Auth0 FIle in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, auth0, karma-coverage

Following is the auth0 service file which is getting used for authentication for the application.
**import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';**
Using auth0 module I created stub file for testing auth0 service file.Unit testing is getting done in Jasmine Karma.
Test is getting passed but  without any coverage. Hence of no use.
Please help to find out errors in the unit testing code.

**Auth0 Service File**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private _Auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_ID,
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_DOMAIN,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.REDIRECT,
    audience: AUTH_CONFIG.AUDIENCE,
    scope: AUTH_CONFIG.SCOPE
  });

  userProfile: UserProfile;
  accessToken: string;
  expiresAt: number;
  loggedIn: boolean;
  loggedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.loggedIn);

  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }

  login() {
    this._Auth0.authorize({ connection: 'value ....' });
  }

  handleLoginCallback() {
    this._Auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken) {
        window.location.hash = '';
        this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
        this.getUserInfo(authResult);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      } else if (err) {
        console.error(`Error: ${err.error}`);
      } else {
        console.log('Authentication not successful');
      }
    });
  }

  getUserInfo(authResult) {
    this._Auth0.client.userInfo(authResult.accessToken, (err,  profile)  =>  {
      this._setSession(authResult,  profile);
    });
    if  (authResult.idTokenPayload.user_metadata) {   
      let decodedToken = jwt_decode(authResult.accessToken);
      decodedToken["https://api.test.net/roles"].forEach(role => {
        if (role == "COMMON_EXCEPTIONHANDLER_UPDATER") {
          localStorage.setItem("perm", 'write');
        }
      }); 
      localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser',
     `${authResult.idTokenPayload.user_metadata.username}@${authResult.idTokenPayload.name}`);
    }
  }

  private _setSession(authResult, profile) {
    this.expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn * 1000 + Date.now();
    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken;
    this.userProfile = profile;
    this._setLoggedIn(true);
  }

  logout() {
    this._Auth0.logout({
      returnTo: environment.returnTo,
      clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.CLIENT_ID
    });
    localStorage.removeItem('loggedInUser');
  }

  private _setLoggedIn(value: boolean) {
    this.loggedIn$.next(value);
    this.loggedIn = value;
  }

  get authenticated(): boolean {
    return (Date.now() < this.expiresAt) && this.loggedIn;
  }
}

**Following is the stub file created**

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
export class Auth0SecurityServiceStub {
    authorize() {}

    parseHash() {
        return { user: 'bob', idToken: 'token' };
    }

    logout() { return of(true);}

    authenticated() {
        return true;
    }

    accessToken = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVC";

    userProfile: {
        "sub": "waad|nwr1ZvxhR3Bdpn4Xapd9i9F_x48y0cdrqQ5mTQeNjjI",
        "given_name": "test1",
        "family_name": "test3",
        "nickname": "M@test.com",
        "name": "test",
        "picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/0cd89133dd90b50a34e97da7d146cc45?s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fmm.png",
        "updated_at": "2021-08-03T15",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "email_verified": true
    };
    expiresAt = '1628012228162';
    loggedIn = true;
}
```

Please help how to get code covered with proper testing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended that you query the auth0 API during testing. Instead, you should mock the service. https://auth0.com/docs/deploy-monitor/pre-deployment-checks/predeployment-tests